# How can I remove an item from an array in an array in ionic 4

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic4

I want to remove an item that I select from an array in myItemsList. For example the first array in myItemsList has only one item that "First item" and I want to remove it.

```
 myItemsList = [["First item"],["2"],["3"],["4"],["5"],["6"],["7"],["8"],["9"],["10"],["11","12"],["13"],["14"]]; //this is my array of arrays in ts file

 delete(myitems){


  }    //and this is the function that supposed to delete item.
```

Answer (score 1):

If `selected` is array of `['First item', '3', '12']`

```
var myItemsList = [["First item"],["2"],["3"],["4"],["5"],["6"],["7"],["8"],["9"],["10"],["11","12"],["13"],["14"]]; //this is my array of arrays in ts file
var selected = ['First item', '3', '12'];

myItemsList.map(function(items) {
  return items.filter((item) => selected.indexOf(item) === -1);
});
```

result: [[], ["2"], [], ["4"], ["5"], ["6"], ["7"], ["8"], ["9"], ["10"], ["11"], ["13"], ["14"]]

If after you will need remove an empty arrays from myItemsList:

```
myItemsList = myItemsList.filter((items) => items.length);
```

result: [["2"], ["4"], ["5"], ["6"], ["7"], ["8"], ["9"], ["10"], ["11"], ["13"], ["14"]]